# SharePoint: jQuery toggle removing all SharePoint top divs, leaves space on bottom of web page?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, sharepoint, toggle, margin

So I have a jquery toggle event on a button for a SharePoint 2010 page. If clicked it just hides the SharePoint constructs:

```
$('#s4-topheader2,#s4-titlerow,#RibbonContainer,#s4-ribbonrow').toggle(500);
```

works fine, but after it is used the web page doesn't reach to the bottom of the page anymore? only after the top divs are brought back. So I am guessing there is a little piece I could add to get around this? why is this the case?

Comment: What do you mean it "doesn't reach to the bottom of the page"? There is no scroll?

Comment: there is a scroll, but it ends about 30px above the bottom of the browser window, so there is this white space that remains until I toggle back the SharePoint divs.

Comment: sorry I mean the s4-workspace (body) of the page is cut off about 30-50px above the bottom browser window frame. Its like dead white space...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code works fine for me in IE and Chrome but if you want to re-size s4-workspace manually you should re-size after the animation has finished like:

```
$('#s4-topheader2,#s4-titlerow,#RibbonContainer,#s4-ribbonrow').toggle(500, function(){
    $('#s4-workspace').height($(window).height());
});
```

Comment: yeah it is really weird, but the above totally fixes it for me so thanks. still curious why though...